# Exclude requests in Apache mod_status

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring

I'm using the following command to watch apache status :

`watch -n 1 links -dump http://localhost/server-status`

but in here , is a problem with the status. 
in the status page , the request for `localhost/server-status` is on the list.

Is there any way to remove it ?

thanks,

Comment: Even if based on a slightly different question, I bet that [this other answer](http://serverfault.com/a/713169/251104) should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't remove it because it's a request like another one.

The problem with your monitoring is that your are doing requests every second to know the status and it's making your monitoring counterproductive.

The best way for you could be to make requests every minute instead of every second. This page doesn't need to be requested every second because the information provided is the total in that moment or an average.